# Costs vs Consistant gets

Tags: database, sql-execution-plan

What does it indicate to see a query that has a low cost in the explain plan but a high consistent gets count in autotrace? In this case the cost was in the 100's and the CR's were in the millions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cost can represent two different things depending on version and whether you are running in cpu-based costing mode or not.

Briefly, the cost represents that amount of time that the optimizer expects the query to execute for, but it is expressed in units of the amount of time that a single block read takes. For example if Oracle expects a single block read to take 1ms and the query to take 20ms, then the cost equals 20.

Consistent gets do not match exactly with this for a number of reasons: the cost includes non-consistent (current) gets (eg reading and writing temp data), the cost includes CPU time, and a consistent get can be a multiblock read instead of a single block read and hence have a different duration. Oracle can also get the estimate of the cost completely wrong and it could end up requiring a lot more or less consistent gets than the estimate suggested.

A useful method that can helo explain disconnects between predicted execution plan and actual performance is "cardinality feedback". See this presentation: http://www.centrexcc.com/Tuning%20by%20Cardinality%20Feedback.ppt.pdf

Answer (score 4):

At best, the cost is the optimizer's estimate of the number of I/O's that a query would perform.  So, at best, the cost is only likely to be accurate if the optimizer has found a very good plan-- if the optimizer's estimate of the cost is correct and the plan is ideal, that generally means that you're never going to bother looking at the plan because that query is going to perform reasonably well.

Consistent gets, however, is an actual measure of the number of gets that a query actually performed.  So that is a much more accurate benchmark to use.

Although there are many, many things that can influence the cost, and a few things that can influence the number of consistent gets, it is probably reasonable to expect that if you have a very low cost and a very high number of consistent gets that the optimizer is probably working with poor estimates of the cardinality of the various steps (the ROWS column in the PLAN_TABLE tells you the expected number of rows returned in each step).  That may indicate that you have missing or outdated statistics, that you are missing some histograms, that your initialization parameters or system statistics are wrong in some way, or that the CBO has problems for some other reason estimating the cardinality of your results.

What version of Oracle are you using?